# How to display selected items in a DataGrid to a TextBox using VB.NEW and WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid

I am stuck with what might seem as a rather simple problem, I am using *WPF* with *VB.NET 2010*.
I populated my `DataGrid` with data from a *MySQL* database, I want when I click on a specific row on the `DataGrid`, the row content is displayed in a `TextBox`, I tried using *VB.NET WinForms* code but it doesn't seem to work.

```
Dim i as integer
i = dgvGrid.CurrentRow.Index
textbox1.text = dgvGrid.Item(0, i).Value
```

That is a sample code that I'd use in *WinForms*
Please help!

Comment: Are you already tried to use DataBinding between controls ?

Comment: No not yet i haven't, i recently shifted from winforms so am still learning WPF.

Comment: `I recently shifted from winforms` - Welcome to the light side. Please forget everything you've ever learned from winforms and make sure you don't apply that in WPF.

Comment: Ok, So, You should read that : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29054/WPF-Data-Binding-Part-1

After that, I think you could solve your problem yourself :-)

Answer (score 0):

I found how to do this atlast,

```
Dim row as datarowView = Ctype(Datagrid1.selectedItem(0),Datarowview)
textbox1.text = string.format(Trim(row("ColumnName").ToString
```

ColumnName is just The name of the columnheader in the datagrid